# is it possible to restrict concurrent insert in oracle database

Tags: java, database, oracle

I have to restrict concurrent insert in oracle database.

Is it possible without manually checking 
or is there anything in oracle database which restrict the second transaction by same user
or is there anything in jdbc?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "restrict"? What should the second transaction do - block until the first transaction is committed or fail with an error message?

Comment: second transaction must failed. Currently both transaction success and data inserted into table.

Comment: Do you have control over the SQL statements? Means, would a `SELECT FOR UPDATE NOWAIT` help?

Comment: SELECT FOR UPDATE NOWAIT will surely worked in case of update. But my case is of inserting the record.

Comment: What is the business problem you are trying to solve?  Why do you want to prevent the "same user" from doing concurrent inserts but not, apparently, to prevent different users from doing those same concurrent inserts?  What problem does concurrent inserts create?  Are you sure you don't simply need a unique constraint?

Comment: As @JustinCave says, it might help if you give us some background on the problem you are trying to solve. Otherwise, there is also [`LOCK TABLE NOWAIT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9015.htm)

Comment: Yes i need the same thing that unique constraint does. But in my case i can't check as multiple fields are involved. Also i need something in oracle which should work like unique constraint does.

Comment: i want something which checks at run time(means not specified in table design). in case of unique constraint we provide unique key at the time of databse design.

Comment: let me tell you the business login. i have userid stdate and eddate fields. now i want to check the same user should not insert record between stdate and eddate concurrently.

Comment: i have userid startTime(date and time) and endTime fields. now i want to check the same user should not insert record between startTime and endTime concurrently, while different users can do it. How would i check the same? Currently two records are inserted in db. i want 1 to insert and 2nd should failed.

Answer (score 0):

you should use a materialized view to define such a constraint.

first approach:

```
create table froc3(id number,
                   userid number,
                   starttime date,
                   endtime date,
                   constraint froc3_id unique(id));

create materialized view froc3_mv refresh on commit as
  select f1.id as id, f2.id as id_conflict
    from froc3 f2, froc3 f1
   where f2.userid = f1.userid
     and f2.id <> f1.id
     and (f2.starttime between f1.starttime and f1.endtime or
         f2.endtime between f1.starttime and f1.endtime);

alter table froc3_mv add constraint check_interval check(id =
                                                         id_conflict) deferrable;
```